# GRPC c++ channelz example

Tags: c++, grpc

I found there is an introduction to channelz on Go and Java language.

https://grpc.io/blog/a-short-introduction-to-channelz/

It seems greate for debugging.

It says Support for C++ and wrapped languages is coming soon on September 05, 2018.

Does C++ support channelz or not now? Anyone know how to add channelz in C++ languge? Any example code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: from a quick google it looks implemented https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/15988 https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/86f93801e5d452cff40d6958d21a8eb211da0654/src/cpp/server/channelz

Answer (score 2):

It's still marked as experimental in C++, because it's still missing a few of the lower-level fields (e.g., socket-level data).  But overall it is quite usable.  You can enable it using the following API:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/223652d4087d53fbf80c28dc20c31491209f86e7/include/grpcpp/ext/channelz_service_plugin.h#L35

Comment: I see. Thanks you.